# How to get the id of a post from django and use it on javascript?

Tags: javascript, django

I have posts that I'd like to edit. The thing is they're inside a for loop and I don't know which one the user is going to click. How could I do this?

Template:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {% if request.user == post.poster %}
        <a id="editPost-{{ post.id }}" href="javascript:;" style="display: block;">Edit</a>

        <form id="editForm-{{ post.id }}" style="display: none;" method="POST" action="{% url 'editPost' post.id %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control">{{ post.content }}</textarea>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    {% endif %}

    <p id="postContent-{{ post.id }}">{{ post.content }}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

JS:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
const editBtn = document.querySelector('#editPost');
const postContent = document.querySelector('#postContent');
const editForm = document.querySelector('#editForm');

editBtn.style.display = 'block';
postContent.style.display = 'block';
editForm.style.display = 'none';

editBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    editBtn.style.display = 'none';
    editForm.style.display = 'block';
    postContent.style.display = 'none';
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually pass the id to the django form in forms.py when it is generated instead of trying pull the value onto the page using HTMX. You could even create an init function or some kind of function that looks at a database value for the next ID.

For example:

```
class AccountForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label='Name', max_length=100, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'id':'NameEntry'}))
```

Or maybe even:

```
class AccountForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label='Name', max_length=100, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'id':nextLoopID()}))
```

Then in your javascript just make sure you wait for the page to load the form before attaching any event listeners. The classic [jquery](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) line is recommended:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
// Your code here
});
```